# SQL Rank column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

[image: RankFunction]

From the table data I should derive the Rank column.
Aim is to select Unique Duns based on below conditions:

1. Max(ConfidenceCode)
2. If Confindencde is same, If DeliveryAddressSeq=0 has just one row select that
3. If Confindencde is same, If DeliveryAddressSeq=0 has many rows then select min of CustomerCode

So, finally I require `Rank=1` data as desired output

Comment: Read how to apply rank from here https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/12/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-ranking-functions-rank-dense_rank-and-row_number-day-12-of-35/

Comment: What if Confindencde is same and DeliveryAddressSeq != 0 ?

Comment: I know how to apply Rank, But this is not strait fwd.

Comment: Hi Jon, The DeliveryAddreessSeq=0 is one or more.

Comment: Can you provide a non-image example of your data? Also, I don't understand your last comment re:Jon. For example, you have rows with no Rank specified. How should those be ranked? ie DUNS 1003, Customer Code 506.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I dont mind ranking other. i am interested in only Rank=1 rows  in each DUNS, other you can ignore or can give next number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rank` window function should do the trick:

```
SELECT Duns, ConfidenceCode, DeliveryAddressSeq, CustomerCode
FROM   (SELECT Duns, ConfidenceCode, DeliveryAddressSeq, CustomerCode,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY duns
                            ORDER BY ConfidenceCode ASC,
                                     CASE DeliveryAddressSeq WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                                                             ELSE 1 
                                     END ASC,
                                     CustomerCode DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: Mureinik, You are really wonder man :-) I was wondering on how to rank on equal condition. The case statement did the trick i was looking

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to have the rank 1 only, you were looking for customercode 501, 504, 507

```
SELECT duns, 
       confidencecode, 
       deliveryaddressseq, 
       customercode,
       [rank]
  FROM (SELECT *,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY duns
                                ORDER BY confidencecode DESC,
                                         deliveryaddressseq,
                                         customercode) AS [rank]
          FROM   t_duns) tt
 WHERE [rank] = 1
```

Result

```
duns    confidencecode  deliveryaddressseq  customercode    rank
1001    10              1                   501             1
1002    10              0                   504             1
1003    10              0                   507             1
```